# Why isn't Google Analytics data being recorded when the snippeted it between the `</head>` and `</body>` tags?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, tracking

I am really confused with this one, I added the Google Analytics code in my page below the `</head>` or before `</body>` but the code is not being marked as connected inside the analytics panel.

I tested it with the Google analytics debug plug-in and it seems to connect appropriately.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Was this after the <body> tag?

Comment: In general yes the code is within <body> </body> tags

Comment: Do you mean the data isn't showing in analytics? That takes at least a day to start appearing.

Comment: it's there for about half month and no data :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added the tag in the correct place, it should be with the `<head> </head>` tags. This could be the reason why it isnt tracking.

Also if your are using the [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) plugin for Chrome, it should have pointed this error out to you, did it not?

Have you double checked you have pasted in the correct code? Sounds obvious but had a client who had made this mistake before, missed of a character when adding the code.

Comment: It worked a few hours later, there was a mistake on the ID in the analytics code for some reason and it was fixed.
Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

It might take a while for it to update your status. Have you tried going to your Real-Time Tab - Overview (it right above Audience Tab) and see if you are capturing hits? If you see hits then you are good to go. In some cases tracking code status doesn't update ever but data gets sent to your property.

Note: if you have a filter set to exclude your own IP then your visits won't show up.